# copy list of files in a specified location

Tags: windows, batch-file

I need to go through a list to copy the specified files into another location.
This is the used .bat file:

```
for /f "delims=" %%i in ('C:\Users\Documents\test\data\list_1.4.txt') do copy "C:\Users\Documents\test\data\Golden\%%i" "C:\Users\Documents\test\data\data_1.4"
```

But this does not work.
Any help?

I tried this too

```
@echo off
set src=C:\Users\Documents\test\data\Golden
set dst=C:\Users\Documents\test\data\data_1.4
set file=C:\Users\Documents\est\data\list_1.4.txt

for /F "usebackq tokens=*" %%a in ("%file%") do xcopy "%src%\*%%~a*" "%dst%" /C /Q /H /R /K /Y 1>nul 2>nul
pause
```

Comment: `for /f "usebackq delims=" %%i in ("C:\Users\Documents\test\data\list_1.4.txt") do copy "%%~fi" "C:\Users\Documents\test\data\data_1.4"`

Comment: Thank you for answering , i have now an error message that indicates, specified file is not found. I am sure about file's path

Comment: Let me post an answer..

Comment: This is the content of list_1.4.txt:
C:\Users\Documents\test\data\Golden\applicability\framebuilder_fs.xml
C:\Users\Documents\test\data\Golden\barcelona\backbone_sysconf.empty.xml

Comment: ok, then the answer below should work. Only time it will not work is if the file does not exist in the location specified.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comment, the file content is something like:

```
"C:\Users\Documents\test\data\Golden\file1.txt"
"C:\Users\Documents\test\data\Golden\file2.pdf"
"C:\Users\Documents\test\data\Golden\file3.exe"
```

If that is the case, then:

```
@echo off
set "dest=C:\Users\Documents\test\data\data_1.4"
set "file=C:\Users\Documents\est\data\list_1.4.txt"
for /f "usebackq delims=" %%i in ("%file%") do (
    if exist "%%~fi" copy /Y "%%~fi" "%destination%"
)
```